# What is the difference between {@code memberData} and <code>memberData</code> in JavaDoc

Tags: java, javadoc

What is the difference between `{@code memberData}` and `<code>memberData</code>` in JavaDoc

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are two main differences:

1. `{@code ...}` is more concise: easier to read (and type).
2. Text within `{@code ...}` will be automatically HTML-escaped for you.

   For example, `{@code List<String>}` is equivalent to  `<code>List&lt;String&gt;</code>`.

See also [the documentation for `{@code}`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@code%7D).

Comment: The automatic HTML-escaping is especially important for readability of the source code.

Comment: Thanks. The escaping thing is vital to understand that there is actually a difference between the two.

Answer (score 6):

The `{@code}` is equivalent to `<code>` except that it uses allows you to use angle brackets `<` and `>` instead of HTML-entities `&lt;` and `&gt`.

Example:

```
{@code LinkedList<String>}
```

The Javadoc knows how to interpret it as `<code>` without the need of generating HTML.

Comment: `{@link}` creates a link. `{@code}` normally does not. Your description of `<code>` is also a bit funny... From Javadoc's point of view `<code>` is just an HTML tag that gets passed through, so how it's rendered is up to the browser, while `{@code}` is a directive that Javadoc actually processes on its own. Also, I'm pretty sure `{@code}` produces `<code>` tags in the output too, so the rendering in the browser wil be the same.